# Packaging Qt app - theme

Tags: kubuntu, snap

I packaged Qt application using snapcraft and desktop-qt launcher. The app is build inside `classic` environment (Ubuntu 16.04) using Qt 5.5 and I run it on Kubuntu 17.04 with KDE.

The app doesn't respect Qt theme. For some reason it uses Gtk theme.

How can force it to use system Qt theme?

Answer (score 1):

Executing the snap with the parameter `-style=Fusion` did a great job for me on KDE Neon. In my case I did that with QOwnNotes: `qownnotes -style=Fusion`

Edit: You can use `qDebug() << QStyleFactory::keys().join(" ");` to see which styles are available.

Answer (score 0):

`snap` has it own core so the app just use default or fall-back theme. There are some options to force it:

- Set `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=...` in snap `environment:`
- Make snap wrapper launch the app with `-style=...` option
- There should be also a way to force style from inside app (I just don't know much about Qt)

**References:**

- [Qt5 - QApplication Class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#QApplication)